Adjacent loops in row for Oracle BI Publisher
I have an xml sample similar to this:
<LIST>
<G_1>
 <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>1</EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
<G_2>
 <ELEMENT>Basic</ELEMENT>
 <VALUE>10</VALUE>
 <GROSS>12</GROSS>
 <TYPE>Earning</TYPE>
</G_2>
<G_2>
 <ELEMENT>Transport</ELEMENT>
 <VALUE>11</VALUE>
 <TYPE>Earning</TYPE>
 <GROSS>15</GROSS>
</G_2>
<G_2>
 <ELEMENT>Food</ELEMENT>
 <VALUE>7</VALUE>
 <TYPE>Earning</TYPE>
 <GROSS>8</GROSS>
</G_2>
<G_2>
 <ELEMENT>Tax</ELEMENT>
 <VALUE>5</VALUE>
 <TYPE>Deduction</TYPE>
</G_2>
<G_2>
 <ELEMENT>Pension</ELEMENT>
 <VALUE>3</VALUE>
 <TYPE>Deduction</TYPE>
</G_2>
</G_1>
</LIST>

Now I have created a table with 5 columns and I want to loop through all the employee records (G_1).
The first 3 columns will be for G_2 records of type Earning, then the next two will be for Deduction. So we should have:
ELEMENT  |  VALUE   |   GROSS    |   ELEMENT     |   VALUE
Basic        10          12          Tax              5
Transport     11         15          Pension          3
Food          7           7

I have tried two for-each loops in my row like:
for-each:G_2[TYPE='Earnings']  ELEMENT  RESULT  GROSS end  for-each:G_2[TYPE='Deductions'] ELEMENT   RESULT end

But this only works for the first 3 columns but returns blank for the rest (Deductions).
Any one have an idea of workaround?
I have even tried a for and end with each column cell but that hasn't worked either.
This is basically a payslip report with earnings in one group of columns and deductions on another.
Thanks

I don't know bi-publisher, myself, but I have the impression it provides a GUI for authoring XSLT; are you able to actually view and edit the XSLT code as XML? If so, this would probably have an easy solution

I found the answer
This is what I am using.
As you know I want 5 columns.
For each page of the report I have at the top:
<?for-each@section:G_1?><?sort:EMPLOYEE_NUMBER;'ascending';data-type='text'?>

Then at the end of the page
<?end for-each?>

These are the columns we want for the table:
ELEMENT  |  VALUE   |   GROSS    |   ELEMENT     |   VALUE

Now for each of the columns in the table (rtf document), I have:
<?for-each-group:G_2[TYPE='Earning'];ELEMENT?><?sort:ELEMENT;'ascending';data-type='text'?>
  <?ELEMENT?>
<?end for-each-group?>

<?for-each-group:G_2[TYPE='Earning'];ELEMENT?><?sort:ELEMENT;'ascending';data-type='text'?>
<?sum(current-group()/VALUE)?>
<?end for-each-group?>

<?for-each-group:G_2[TYPE='Earning'];ELEMENT?><?sort:ELEMENT;'ascending';data-type='text'?>
<?sum(current-group()/GROSS)?>
<?end for-each-group?>

<?for-each-group:G_2[TYPE='Deduction'];ELEMENT?><?sort:ELEMENT;'ascending';data-type='text'?>
<?ELEMENT?>
<?end for-each-group?>

<?for-each-group:G_2[TYPE='Deduction'];ELEMENT?><?sort:ELEMENT;'ascending';data-type='text'?>
<?sum(current-group()/VALUE)?>
<?end for-each-group?>


G_2 does not loop all the way, maybe BIP is optimizing somewhere when the first loop is over.
Try looping through G_1 in both places unconditionally, and your G_2 loop inside, with conditions.
